# How to unroll a certain loop with certain params like max-unroll-times in GCC

Tags: c++, c, gcc, parameters, unroll

How should I write my code if I want GCC to unroll one of loops in
my code with certain params like max-unroll-times in GCC?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#pragma GCC push_options
#pragma GCC optimize ("O3", "unroll-loops")
void func()
{
    #pragma GCC unroll 4
    for (...)
    {
    }
}
#pragma GCC pop_options
```

The params like `max-unroll-times` don't seem to be controllable via `#pragma`; if you really need different values for different loops, move each loop to a function in a separate file and compile with exactly the options you need.

Comment: `#pragma GCC unroll 4` may be closer to what the OP was looking for.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: I see that's new in GCC 8.  Thanks for pointing it out, I had no idea (and by the way it appears to be undocumented).